# [angular]: checkbox which disappear with toggle button

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I build a form that contains several checkboxes. When I click a button in the "yes" position, the checkboxes appear and then disappear when I click the button on 'no'.

But the check mark disappears when I do theses steps:
for the example, I check "invalidityCheckbox": here's the workflow:

1. I go to the page : checkboxes are only visible if this button is check to "oui" : it's ok

[image]

2. the checkboxes are displayed: I check "invalidité" which triggers the display of an input element: it's ok.

[image]

3/I check the button again in the "no" position which makes all the checkboxes disappear: it's OK

4/when I check again the button on "oui" position the mark of the checkbox has disappeared. KO

[image]

These checkboxes come from a child component and are instantiated in the parent like this:

The checkbox component:
Html:

```
  <div class="c-form__tooltip align-items-center u-margin-bottom& md u-margin-bottom sm@tablet">
    <div class="c-input-checkbox-list u-margin-bottom-sm" [ngClass]="{'error' : formControl.invalid && formControl.touched}">
      <input type="checkbox" name="{{ formControlName }}" id="{{ formControlName }}" (change)="checkValue($event)">
      <label for="{{ formControlName }}">{{ page + '.' + formControlName | translate }}</label>
    </div>
    <div class="c-tooltip">
      <i class="c-tooltip__icon icon-question-circle-5"></i>
      <span class="c-tooltip__text" style="width:450px">
        <!--{{ page + '.tooltip'  | translate }}-->
        tooltip test temporaire
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

the TS file:

```
export class CheckBoxComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {

  @Input() public formControl: FormControl;
  @Input() public formControlName: string;
  @Input() public page: string;
  @Input() public index: number = 0;

  @Output() public onChecked: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  @ViewChild(FormControlDirective, {static: true})
  public formControlDirective: FormControlDirective;

  get control(): any {
    return this.formControl || this.controlContainer.control.get(this.formControlName);
  }

  constructor(private controlContainer: ControlContainer) {
  }
// Voir si possible supprimer ControlValueAccessor
  public registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
   // console.log(this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.registerOnTouched(fn);)
  }

  public registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
   // console.log('this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.registerOnChange(fn);');
  }

  public writeValue(obj: any): void {
   // console.log('this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.writeValue(obj);');
  }

  public setDisabledState(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    // this.formControlDirective.valueAccessor.setDisabledState(isDisabled);
  }

  public checkValue(isChecked: any): void {
    this.onChecked.emit(isChecked);
  }
```

Here's one implementation in the parent:

```
<amp-check-box
          [formControl] = form.controls.deathPTIACheckbox
          [formControlName] = "'deathPTIACheckbox'"
          [page] = page
          (onChecked)="isDeathPTIACheckBoxChecked($event)">
        </amp-check-box>
```

and the TS:

```
 private static addControlsInvalidity(invalidityGroup: FormGroup): void {
    invalidityGroup.addControl('invalidityInput', new FormControl(0, [Validators.required]));
  }

  private static removeControlsInvalidity(invalidityGroup: FormGroup): void {
    invalidityGroup.removeControl('invalidityInput');
  }

    protected buildForm(): void {
        // Form controls
        this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
          isMutualExpert: ['no', [Validators.required]],
          havePensionContract: ['no', [Validators.required]],
   
          invalidityCheckbox: [false],
          invalidity: this.formBuilder.group([]),
        });

  protected controlForm(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(
    this.form.controls.havePensionContract.valueChanges.subscribe((havePensionContract: string) => {
      havePensionContract === 'yes' ? this.isPensionContract = true : this.isPensionContract = false;
      if (this.isPensionContract && this.isInvalidityChecked) {
        this.form.controls.invalidity.get('invalidityInput').valueChanges.subscribe( invalidityInput => console.log("DISPLAY --- " + 'invalidityInput'));
      }
    }));
  }

  protected initForm(): void {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      // Init Radio buttons
      this.translate.get('initialization').subscribe(() => {
        this.isMutualExpertYesNo = ControlsUtils.getRadioElements('isMutualExpert', this.translate);
        this.havePensionContractYesNo = ControlsUtils.getRadioElements('havePensionContract', this.translate);
        this.isKeepActualGuaranteesPolicyYesNo = ControlsUtils.getRadioElements('isKeepActualGuaranteesPolicy', this.translate);
      })
    );
  }

  public isInvalidityCheckboxChecked(isChecked): void {
    this.isInvalidityChecked = isChecked.target.checked;
    console.log(this.isInvalidityChecked);
    if (this.isInvalidityChecked) {
      Solutions03CurrentProtectionComponent.addControlsInvalidity(this.form.controls.invalidity as FormGroup);
    } else {
      Solutions03CurrentProtectionComponent.removeControlsInvalidity(this.form.controls.invalidity as FormGroup);
    }
  }
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Rather than posing this much code, you could create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). You can use [stackblitz](https://www.stackblitz.com) to make one

Comment: You got it all wrong with the control value accessor, no need to emit anything, you need to call onchange and ontouched which will change the formcontrol value you gave to amp-check-box directly. As for your problem, I cant find deathPTIACheckbox anywhere in the ts file so its hard to know what would triggers the value change

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I forgot to implement the (change) event : (change)="updateCheckboxChecked(isChecked)"